# Группировка sql выборки по временным интервалам

Tags: php, postgresql, group-by, timestamp

Приветствую! Гуру postgres, помогите советом)
Есть задача - нужно сгруппировать большое количество данных по временному интервалу. Интервал может быть - за каждые 30 минут, за час, за 3 часа и т.д. То есть по сути группировка идет по определенным количествам минут.
В принципе задачу я вроде как решил, используя подсказки с ресурса, но не совсем так, как хотелось бы.
Сейчас у меня запрос такого плана:

```
SELECT
  to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from timestamp) / 3600 )) * 3600) as timestamp,
  "curOut"
FROM
  stat
WHERE
  timestamp > '2018-02-27 17:17:18' AND
  timestamp < '2018-02-28 17:17:18'
GROUP BY
  to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from timestamp) / 3600 )) * 3600),
  "curOut"
```

Все бы ничего, но при таком решении в ответ я получаю данные, сгруппированные по часу, но не с текущего момента, а с начала часа:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [timestamp] => 1519819200
        [curOut] => ggh
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [timestamp] => 1519812000
        [curOut] => ffg
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [timestamp] => 1519826400
        [curOut] => jjd
    )
```

Как видно в ответе приходят данные с timestamp часа, начинающегося с 00, т.е. 14:00, 15:00, 16:00 и т.д.

**Задача стоит в том, чтобы при группировке данные брались с учетом текущего времени, т.е. в 17:37 - интервалы должны быть 14:37, 15:37 и т.д.**

Помогите, плиз)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Группируем по разности текущей даты и требуемой даты, округленной до нужного уровня. Для получения времени начала диапазона вычитаем эту округленную разность из текущего времени:

```
select to_timestamp(extract(epoch from now()) -
                    floor(  ((extract(epoch from now())- 
                              extract(epoch from timestamp)) / 3600 )
                         ) * 3600 ) as timestamp,

       "curOut"
  from mytable
  group by floor(((extract(epoch from now()) -
                   extract(epoch from timestamp)) / 3600 )) * 3600,
           "curOut"
```

Comment: Да, это то что нужно. Спасибо огромное за помощь!